# Building and applying a multifunction with different conditions to DataFrame in python

Tags: python, dataframe, function, conditional-statements, series

From the following DataFrame df:

```
    fe_id  em   shift     date     
0   23454   11  18-sh   2019-10-01
1   23454   22  15.1-sh 2019-10-02
2   23454   33  15.2-sh 2019-10-03
3   23454   44  12-sh   2019-10-04
4   23454   55  18-sh   2019-10-05
5   23454   66  18-sh   2019-10-06
6   23454   77  18-sh   2019-10-07
```

I have built several functions, each with different conditions, which have to be checked individually in order to output the defined value.

More precisely, the primary condition is which work shift the employee has, under this condition, the respective function is called, which sets further conditions, whether the date is a holiday and which day the date corresponds to, from this the respective values (120,1320,1440,1080 or 0) are to be given within a new column df[WT].

My goal output should be:

```
    fe_id  em   shift     date      WT     
0   23454   11  18-sh   2019-10-01  1440   
1   23454   22  15.1-sh 2019-10-02  1320
2   23454   33  15.2-sh 2019-10-03  120
3   23454   44  12-sh   2019-10-04  960
4   23454   55  18-sh   2019-10-05  1080
5   23454   66  18-sh   2019-10-06  120
6   23454   77  18-sh   2019-10-07  1440
```

Accordingly, my built-up function looks like this:

```
german_holidays= holidays.DE(years=[])
```

```
def eighteen(date):
 if date in german_holidays:
   return 120
 elif (date + pd.Timedelta(days=1)) in german_holidays:
   return 1320
 elif date.weekday == 5: 
    return 1080
 elif date.weekday == 6: 
    return 120
 else:
    return 1440

----------------------------------------------
def fifteenone(date):
    if date in german_holidays:
        return 120
    elif (date + pd.Timedelta(days=1)) in german_holidays:
        return 1320
    elif date.weekday == 4:
        return 1320
    elif date.weekday == 5:
        return 0
    elif date.weekday == 6: 
        return 120
    else: 
        return 1440

----------------------------------------------
def fifteentwo(date):
    if date in german_holidays: 
        return 120
    elif (date + pd.Timedelta(days=1)) in german_holidays:
        return 1320
    elif date.weekday == 4:
        return 1320
    elif date.weekday == 5:
        return 0
    elif date.weekday == 6:
        return 0
    elif date.weekday == 0:
        return 1080
    else: 
        return 1440

---------------------------------------------
def twelve(date):
    if date in german_holidays: 
        return 0
    elif date.weekday == 5:
        return 0
    elif date.weekday == 6:
        return 0
    else: 
        return 960
```

And the main function that should call and execute all the above defined functions is:

```
def WT(shift, date):
    if shift == "18-sh":
        return eighteen(date)
    elif shift == "15.1-sh":
        return fifteenone(date)
    elif shift == "15.2-sh":
        return fifteentwo(date)
    elif shift == "12-sh":
        return twelve(date)
```

```
df['WT'] = df.apply(lambda row: WT(row['shift'],row['date']),axis=1)
```

In this regard, I receive the following error message:

```
Cannot convert type '<class 'list'>' to date.
```

and

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Unfortunately, I am full of question marks. Is there a better structure of the function and why does this error message appear.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: `df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])`  it works without error when using it.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).